# Memory leaks in animation using matplotlib with performance consideration

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Recently I am doing animation using python with matplotlib. In the beginning I followed the example searched in the net, which has the following structure:

```
=========================================================================
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib.animation as anim

def animate(i):
    ax.clear()
    # Re-plot the figure with updated animation data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig, ax = plot.subplots(fsigsize=(8,4))
    an = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1)
    plot.show()
=========================================================================
```

This code seems ok. There is no memory leaks. But the problem is that it runs too slow. Because when re-generating the plot with updated animation data, all the settings of the plot (e.g., set_xlim(), set_ylim(), ploting axes, .... etc) have to be done again and again. Hence I tried to improve the performance in this way:

```
========================================================================
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib.animation as anim

def init():
    ax.set_title("....")
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
    # plot axes, and all the patterns which are fixed in the animation

def animate(i):
    # x[] and y[] are large arrays with updated animation data
    if ('la' in globals()): la.remove()
    la, = ax.plot(x, y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig, ax = plot.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
    an = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1)
    plot.show()
========================================================================
```

In this way only the major curve "la" is re-ploted. The other fixed parts are done only once in the init() subroutine. Now the animation runs much faster. But serious memory leak appears. Running "top" during animation, I saw that the occupied memory continuously grows up. After testing, I am sure that this statement is the source of memory leaks:

```
la, = ax.plot(x, y)
```

Some discussions indicated that the memory leak is due to the plot "ax" is not closed. But if I do close the plot everytime to update the figure, the performance turns out to be too slow.

Is there a better way to deal with this problem ?

My environment: Python 3.4, matplotlib-1.4.2, Debian GNU/Linux 8.8. I also tested in Python 3.6, matplotlib-2.1.0 under Cygwin and MacOS X. The situation is the same.

Thanks very much for your help.

T.H.Hsieh

Comment: In the code you show, you would get an error `local variable 'la' referenced before assignment`. It is hence not clear what code you are really using and talking about here. See [mcve]. The memory leak could be because `la` is never actually in the global scope, but only local. You would hence also never remove it. But even if you did, removing an artist from the figure does not delete it, so it sticks around in memory. Please look for other solution on how to update plots in animations. They rarely remove anything, but instead set new data to existing artists.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just figure out the answer. The correct way to update the plot in animation, which maintains the performance and without memory leaks, should be "set the new data", instead of "removing and redrawing the curve" or "regenerating the plot". Hence my code should be changed to:

```
=====================================================================
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib.animation as anim

def init():
    global ax, la
    ax.set_title("....")
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
    # get the initial data x[], y[] to plot the initial curve
    la, = ax.plot(x, y, color="red", lw=1)

def animate(i):
    global fig, la
    # update the data x[], y[], set the updated data, and redraw.
    la.set_xdata(x)
    la.set_ydata(y)
    fig.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig, ax = plot.subplots(fsigsize=(8,4))
    an = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1)
    plot.show()
=====================================================================
```

In any case, thanks to those guys who gave me comments, which indicated me to find the answer.

Best Regards,

T.H.Hsieh

Comment: In any case my first comment below the question still applies.